# In function ‘displayBox’: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Tags: c

I'm getting this error and I have no idea why. w9_in_lab.c: In function ‘displayBox’:  w9_in_lab.c:194:4: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

```
void displayBox(const char filename[], int id2Find)
{
FILE * fp = NULL;
struct Box b;
int record = 2;
fp = fopen("storage.txt", "r");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    searchBox(fp, id2Find);
    rewind(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf %lf", &b.id, &b.size[0], &b.size[1], &b.size[2], &b.weight);
    while (b.id != id2Find && fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf %lf", &b.id, &b.size[0], &b.size[1], &b.size[2], &b.weight) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf %lf", &b.id, &b.size[0], &b.size[1],    &b.size[2], &b.weight);
        record++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (b.id == id2Find)
    {
        printf("Found box %d as record #%d\n", id2Find, record);
        printBox(b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This box is not recorded.\n\n", id2Find, record);
    }
 }

 else
 {
    printf("Error opening file");
 }
 }
```

Comment: NVM I found the issue

Comment: The line `printf("This box is not recorded.\n\n", id2Find, record);` has two arguments to `printf()` that are not used by the format string.  In future, please identify line 194 — there's no way we can tell which is line 194 unless you tell us, and there's no way you should post 194 lines of code either (so simply posting all the code was not an option; thank you for not taking it).